# SEDE's still got the old-school footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, footer

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) needs its footer updating from this:

> [image]

To the new one:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've [submitted a pull request for this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/12) the other day, although it's to just remove the list of sites altogether (and synchronize the CSS a little):

[image: fixed Data Explorer footer]

Linking to the [full list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) seemed more practical than attempting to keep the footer up to date with all of those categories.

Additionally, the legal page will now point to the [version on the Stack Exchange hub](https://stackexchange.com/legal) to avoid inconsistencies that arise from changes there, and the contact link points to the contact page on Meta instead of the team email.